# Why db files have been returned to commit state on my Heroku app every day?

Tags: database, heroku

Please help me. I use sqlite3 as database but the changes I made don't persist to the next day. I have tried with NeDB and the same happens. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku dynos will cycle every 24 hours. Anything that you've written to a dyno's ephemeral file system will be discarded. See here for more details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

Use a persisted data store like PostgreSQL or MongoDB instead.